# M2 - Forget selected shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout, database, shipping-methods, cookie

I'm working on the Checkout page and I noticed that, as a logged-in customer, Magento 2 will remember the Shipping Method you selected the last time you placed an order (for example: "Flat Rate").

How can I force it to forget it? I tried removing cookies, local storage, and even with Incognito mode. Is it storing the data somewhere on the database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check database table: "quote_address" in that column: "shipping_method"

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. that did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was giving by @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd. on the comments:

The last Shipping Method selected is stored in the database table `quote_address`, column `shipping_method`.